# Tracking counts of examples used in training

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement the CBOW word2vec model based on the skipgrams implementation on the tensorflow repository:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.10.0/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py

I have [previously implemented](https://gist.github.com/yxtay/a94d971955d901c4690129580a4eafb9) the simplified version following the TensorFlow tutorials, so I understand that I will have to modify the data batching function as well as a small part of the graph to get the context embedding.

In the skipgram implementation, the data batching function is used in lines [348-351](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.10.0/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L348-L353).

```
(words, counts, words_per_epoch, self._epoch, self._words, examples,
 labels) = word2vec.skipgram(filename=opts.train_data,
                             batch_size=opts.batch_size,
                             window_size=opts.window_size,
                             min_count=opts.min_count,
                             subsample=opts.subsample)
```

From my understanding, the variables assigned are as follows:

- `words`: terms in the vocabulary
- `counts`: associated counts of terms used in the corpus
- `words_per_epoch`: total word count in the corpus
- `self._epoch`: current count of epochs used
- `self._words`: current count of training examples used
- `examples`: current batch of training examples
- `labels`: current batch of training labels

I have managed to replicate the tensor for `words`, `counts`, `words_per_epoch`, `examples` and `labels`. However, `self._epoch` and `self._words` have eluded me. If my understanding is correct, I need to be able to track the count of the training examples used. However, this is not provided by the [sample batching function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch). The counts are later used in a multi-threaded manner to terminate the training loop, hence I can't simply use a loop to add up the counts.

I understand that bits of the tensorflow ops are implemented in C++. However, as I am not familiar with C++, I will have to replicate those parts using Python.

Will be great if I can get some suggestions to obtain the tensor for `self._words`. The tensor basically has to increment only when every time a new batch of examples/labels are called. With that, I can simply use a `self._epoch = self._words // words_per_epoch` to get the other tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the trick while looking at the source code for [tensorflow.models.embedding.word2vec_optimized.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py). Specifically, how `global_step` was incremented when `loss` was called in [lines 218-225](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec_optimized.py#L218-L225).

In my case, I would have to do it as so:

```
# codes to prepare features and labels tensors

data_processed = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.int64)
epochs_processed = data_processed // data_per_epoch

inc_op = data_processed.assign_add(batch_size)
with tf.control_dependencies([inc_op]):
    features_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.batch([features, labels],
                                                  batch_size=batch_size)
```

In this case, the tensor `data_processed` will always be incremented by `batch_size` whenever `features_batch` or `labels_batch` is called. `epochs_processed` will also be incremented accordingly.

The use of [`tf.control_dependencies(control_inputs)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.control_dependencies) is key here. It returns a context manager. The operations specified in `control_inputs` must be executed before the operations defined in the context.